# Is it possible to reduce Google Web Fonts to one request if I'm using multiple fonts?

Tags: performance, fonts, httpwebrequest, webfonts, google-webfonts

I ran a speed test on my website and one of the suggestions was to reduce my external requests. I am using 3 Google Web Fonts, in effect 3 separate requests. Is it posible to combine these into 1 request?

Answer (score 12):

You can combine several fonts with just one call using the | character. Example:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell|Terminal+Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can load multiple fonts in single request like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Lato:300,400,700,900'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't Fonts (like image assets, JSON objects, or videos) separate resources that need individual requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the three requests by embedding the fonts in [data: URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) inside the CSS - at least in IE9+ and most modern browsers.

note: they also work in IE8, but are limited to 32KB

note2: obviously, you won't get the benefits of the Google CDN, since you'll have to serve the fonts inside your CSS...

Comment: I imagine the benefits of the Google CDN are > than loading them on my server + the 3 requests?

Comment: Hard to say; Google's CDN will almost surely have higher bandwidth and lower latency. Moreover base64-encoded data take up more space. OTOH, it will require an additional DNS lookup and 3 requests instead of one (or zero, if you already have a CSS file). Benchmarking is the only way to know.