# Importing multiple google fonts at once

Tags: html, fonts, google-font-api

Every time in my project, if I've to import multiple google fonts, I've to do like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
```

Is there some better way to do it, so I won't have to use multiple link tags?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566947/is-it-possible-to-reduce-google-web-fonts-to-one-request-if-im-using-multiple-f

Answer (score 0):

If the multiple links work fine its alright to use them the only other way would be to do it via css and that would mean copying all the data from those documents